# Getting ​Transfer-Encoding=chunked instead of content length in soap ws call

Tags: java, web-services, http, soap

I am trying to call two soap ws and from java. When I'm calling these ws from two different java thread it's successfully called but when tried to call in same thread, first call get successful and second call get stuck. I can see both the request in my logs.

I checked tcp dump at server and can see for first request, all the header parameter is set correctly but in second call instead of content-length getting transfer-encoding = chunked.

> first ws call header - 2/15/2018 9:59:40 AM  [*8*]
>   **Content-Length=639**   Content-Type=text/xml;   charset=UTF-8  Accept=*/*  Host=test102.com    User-Agent=Apache CXF
>   2.7.11 SOAPAction="Trackem.Web.Services/ReserveServiceTime" Proxy-Connection=Keep-Alive
>
> Second ws call header - 2/15/2018 10:01:11 AM [*9*]
>   **Transfer-Encoding=chunked**   Content-Type=text/xml;   charset​​=UTF-8  Accept=*/*  Host=test102.com
>   User-Agent=Apache CXF 2.7.11
>   SOAPAction="Trackem.Web.Services/CreateOrUpdateTask"
>   Proxy-Connection=Keep-Alive5:05 PM

Please help me do understand why second call is not working properly?

Here is my java ws method -

```
public P getPort(final Class<P> serviceEndpointInterface, final String ascNode) throws MalformedURLException{

final Bus currThreadBus = BusFactory.getThreadDefaultBus();
ClassLoader originalThreadClassLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
ClassLoader busFactoryClassLoader = BusFactory.class.getClassLoader();

try {
    Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(busFactoryClassLoader);
    BusFactory.setThreadDefaultBus(BusFactory.newInstance().createBus());

    QName qname = new QName(nameSpace, strQName);

    Service service = Service.create(qname);

    P port = null;

    if (CommonUtil.isEmpty(portName)) {
        port = service.getPort(serviceEndpointInterface);
    } else {
        QName portQname = new QName(nameSpace, portName);
        port = service.getPort(portQname, serviceEndpointInterface);
    }

    BindingProvider bp = (BindingProvider) port;
    // Timeout in millis
    bp.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, serviceURL);
    bp.getRequestContext().put(Message.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, Integer.parseInt(connectTimeout));
    bp.getRequestContext().put(Message.RECEIVE_TIMEOUT, Integer.parseInt(requestTimeout));

    final Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(port);
    client.getOutInterceptors().add(new LoggingOutInterceptor());
    client.getInInterceptors().add(new LoggingInInterceptor());

    //Add proxy server details if configured in ASC
    if(!CommonMethods.isEmpty(proxyHost) && !CommonMethods.isEmpty(proxyPort))
    {
        HTTPConduit http = (HTTPConduit) ClientProxy.getClient(port).getConduit();

        http.getClient().setProxyServer(proxyHost);
        http.getClient().setProxyServerPort(Integer.parseInt(proxyPort));

        if(!CommonMethods.isEmpty(proxyUsername) && !CommonMethods.isEmpty(proxyPassword))
        {
            http.getProxyAuthorization().setUserName(proxyUsername);
            http.getProxyAuthorization().setPassword(proxyPassword);
        }
    }
    return port;
}finally {
    BusFactory.setThreadDefaultBus(currThreadBus);
    Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(originalThreadClassLoader);
}}
```

Answer (score -3):

> I solved this issue by disabling chunk transfer in HTTP client.
>   http.getClient().setAllowChunking(false);

I guess, the problem was in my proxy serve see this [link](http://middlewaremagic.com/jboss/?p=980)

Comment: That's not at all helpful.